# Calculate total of values in table cells using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with values as shown below,

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class='price'>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='price'>NA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='price'>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='price'>NA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='price'>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='total'></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My task is to calculate the total of valid values (5, 10 and 20) and display the sum in total cell. The code I tried is,

```
var prices = $('.price'),
    total = 0;

$.each(prices, function(i, price) {
    if (price != 'NA') {
         total = total + price;
    }
});

$('.total').text(total);
```

The issue I am facing is, I am not getting the correct output. Sometimes, the table cell contains empty value instead of 'NA'. I am not sure what I am missing. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the text/html of td element and also parse the value to integer before making the addition:

```
var prices = $('.price');
var total = 0;
 $.each(prices, function(i, price){
  var pc=$(this).text();  
  if (pc!= 'NA'){
       total = total + parseInt(pc,10);
  }});
$('.total').text(total);
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try that now.

Comment: imho `parseFloat` better  then `parseInt`, valid number may be float and it may cause error in calculation

Comment: @Evgeniy: there are no float values in td content.

Comment: What is the use of 10? in parseInt($(this).text(),10). Please clarify.

Comment: If there is no radix parameter, so the interpreter will fall back to the default behaviour, which typically treats numbers as decimal, unless they start with a zero (octal) or 0x (hexadecimal). for example Firefox, Chrome and IE 9+ treat parseInt("077") as parseInt("077", 10). IE8 and below treats it as parseInt("077", 8) That's why you should always specify the radix

Comment: yep, there is no in exampled table, but you cant be sure it will not appear in prod. Just to avoid possible bug it make sense to use `parseFloat`

Answer (score 1):

Use [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to check if the cell contains a value then convert it:

```
$.each(prices, function(i, price){
if (!isNaN($(this).text())){
     total = total + Number($(this).text());
}});
```

Note: if you use "parseInt" it will always return an integer - so if you have decimal values in the table use [Number(String)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Example:_Using_the_Number_object_to_assign_values_to_numeric_variables) which will try to convert everything that looks like a number...

Answer (score 0):

Your code working fine the issue is you concat the total so Use `parseInt()` function parses a string and returns an integer.

```
parseInt($(this).text() , 10);
```

Syntax

```
parseInt(string, radix);
```

Parameters

**string**

> The value to parse. If string is not a string, then it is converted to
>   one. Leading whitespace in the string is ignored.

**radix**

> An integer between 2 and 36 that represents the radix (the base in
>   mathematical numeral systems) of the above mentioned string. Specify
>   10 for the decimal numeral system commonly used by humans. Always
>   specify this parameter to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee
>   predictable behavior. Different implementations produce different
>   results when a radix is not specified.

Answer (score 0):

Since `prices` is jQuery object use [`$.fn.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/), then you need to use [`$.fn.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) to get the text.

Also use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), to convert string to integer.

*Use*

```
var prices = $('.price');
var total = 0;
prices.each(function() {
    var price = $(this).text(); //use the method to get text of cell
    if (price != 'NA') {
        total = total + parseInt(price, 10); //use parseInt to convert to number
    }
});
$('.total').text(total);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var prices = $('.price');
  var total = 0;
  prices.each(function() {
    var price = $(this).text();
    if (price != 'NA') {
      total += parseInt(price, 10);
    }
  });
  $('.total').text(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td class='price'>5</td></tr>
<tr><td class='price'>NA</td></tr>
<tr><td class='price'>10</td></tr>
<tr><td class='price'>NA</td></tr>
<tr><td class='price'>20</td></tr>
<tr><td class='total'></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a fiddle for you... [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brr2nv83/)

```
var total = 0;
$(".price").each(function (i, price) {
    var price = $(this).text();

    if (price != 'NA') {
        total = total + parseInt(price);
    }

    $('.total').text(total);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var prices = $('.price');
var total = 0;
$.each(prices, function(i, price)
{
    var val=$(this).text();
    if (val!="NA" && val!="")
       {
         total = total + parseInt(val);
       }
});

$('.total').text(total);
});
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ywqhp6az/)

Answer (score 0):

Get all tds using jqyery, loop through all tds using jquery each function, then check if the current td contains a number using isNaN. If so, sum that value to the total.

```
var sum = 0, elText;
$('.price').each(function (index, element) { 
    elText = element.innerText;
    isNaN(elText) || (sum += parseInt(elText));
});
$('.total').text(sum);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bq0Lsm7x/2/)